# Qual é a melhor ordem para fragmentos adjetivais? // What's the best order for adjectival fragments?

Tags: adjetivos, ordem-de-expressões, substantivos, ambiguidades

Como estrangeiro, sempre foi uma surpresa no Brasil encontrar expressões do tipo "leite em pó desnatado", dado (para mim) a ambiguidade do substantivo qualificado pelo adjetivo "desnatado".

Insistia que era melhor "leite desnatado em pó", mas muitos amigos Brasileiros também insistiam o contrário.

Existe uma regra geral?

---

As a foreigner, I was always surprised by phrases like "leite em pó desnatado", given (for me, anyway) the ambiguity of which noun gets qualified by "desnatado".

I always used to insist that "leite desnatado em pó" was a better option, but my Brazilian friends always seemed to insist that I was wrong.

Is there a general rule?

---

Tentei adicionar o tag "phrase-order", mas meu(?) karma ainda é inadequado.

Comment: [«Leite desnatado em pó», ou «leite em pó desnatado»?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ordem-de-classificadores-dos-substantivos-leite-desnatado-em-po-ou-leite-em-po-desnatado/33572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não tenho conhecimento da existência de regra sobre esse assunto, e a posição que vou assumir baseia-se apenas na minha intuição enquanto falante nativo: *leite em pó desnatado* ou *leite desnatado em pó* são igualmente corretos. a escolha entre um e outro depende da maneira como o falante, quase de certeza sem se dar conta, classifica mentalmente as coisas. Entretanto, um membro empreendedor da nossa comunidade colocou a questão ao [Ciberdúvidas, que confirma a correção das duas expressões](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ordem-de-classificadores-dos-substantivos-leite-desnatado-em-po-ou-leite-em-po-desnatado/33572).

Uma possibilidade é classificar o leite primeiro de acordo com a forma, líquida ou em pó; considerar cada forma como um produto diferente, e só depois classificar cada um destes produtos quanto ao teor de gordura. Esta **lógica da forma** impõe-se facilmente como natural, por as duas formas serem tão diferentes, e conduz naturalmente a **leite em pó desnatado**. O  [argumentoa presentado pelo Jorge B noutra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1191/163) assume implicitamente que a lógica da forma é a única válida.

Mas também é possível pensar que primeiro o  leite é ou não desnatado, e os dois produtos, leite integral e leite desnatado, só depois são ou não reduzidos a pó. [É assim de facto que o leite em pó desnatado é fabricado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leite_em_p%C3%B3). Mas bastaria o falante acreditar que era assim, mesmo que não fosse, para poder adotar esta **lógica da fabricação**, o que conduz naturalmente a pensar em **leite desnatado em pó**. É esta a lógica que o OP acha mais natural.

A meu ver ambas as lógicas são perfeitamente defensáveis, e *leite em pó desnatado* e *leite desnatado em pó* são expressões igualmente corretas e sinónimas. Uma pesquisa no Google mostra que ambas as classificações mentais são usadas, ainda que a lógica da forma seja muito mais comum que a lógica da fabricação: *leite em pó desnatado* ocorre seis vezes mais que *leite desnatado em pó*, 190 contra 33 milhares. Em várias páginas ocorrem ambas as expressões, o que indica que muitos falantes, ou escreventes neste caso, mudam facilmente de uma para a outra.

Há agora uma coisa curiosa. Em Portugal os temos são leite gordo e leite magro. Ora enquanto *leite desnatado em pó* e *leite em pó desnatado* me soam igualmente bem, *leite magro em pó* soa-me mais natural que *leite em pó magro*, apesar de todas os quatro nomes designarem exatamente o mesmo produto. Talvez a confirmar que não sou o único, na pesquisa do Google, *leite em pó magro* ocorre apenas o dobro das vezes de *leite magro em pó*, (cerca de seis contra três milhares, enquanto no caso dos equivalentes desnatados a diferença é de seis para um).

Agora, o OP levanta o potencial problema da ambiguidade em *leite em pó desnatado*, de se saber se *desnatado* qualifica o pó ou o leite. Este problema não se coloca ao falante nativo. O falante nativo não separa *leite em pó desnatado* em *leite* + *pó desnatado*; separa em *leite em pó* + *desnatado*.

Nem sempre a ordem dos adjetivos é arbitrária. Por exemplo, consideremos os atributos líquido/em pó e barato/caro. Creio que ninguém diria *leite barato em pó*. Ser líquido ou em pó é uma caraterística intrínseca do leite, enquanto ser caro ou barato é uma caraterística externa, mais acidental. Portanto é natural classificar primeiro o leite quanto à forma e só depois quanto ao preço, resultando naturalmente em *leite em pó barato*. No caso anterior, líquido/barato e desnatado/integral são ambos atributos intrínsecos do leite, pelo que a lógica da forma e da fabricação são ambas naturais. Se alguém me falasse em *leite barato em pó* eu possivelmente interpretaria *barato* como *de má qualidade*, adotando uma lógica de fabricação, em que leite líquido de má qualidade fora desidratado.

Comment: Excelente exemplo esse do *leite barato em pó*.

Comment: Realmente leite magro em pó soa melhor, está corretíssimo. Mas no caso de um produto à venda acho que tem muita mais lógica ser *leite em pó magro*. Se em vez de ser em pó fosse achocolatado? *Leite magro achocolatado* e *Leite achocolatado magro* qual te soa melhor?

Comment: É, mas repara que há uma diferença. Ser barato não é uma propriedade intrínseca do leite. Já ser magro e ser pó são ambas propriedades intrínsecas. Eu posso imaginar o leite a ser desnatado e depois reduzido a pó, o que sugere leite desnatado em pó. Mas não faz sentido pensar no leite ser barato primeiro e depois reduzido a pó. isso poderia até ser verdade, mas não significa que o leite fosse barato para o consumidor final. É por isso, que se o preço pago pelo consumidor é baixo, tem que ser _leite em pó barato_.

Comment: Jacinto vê o exemplo que dei a seguir.

Comment: Eu poderia concordar, mas teria que insistir na ortografia Saramaguesca "leite-em-pó", com todos os hífens.

Comment: _Leite magro em pó_ soa-me bem enquanto produto à venda. Acho que isto depende do esquema mental. Nalguns casos a ordem não é muito relevante (desnatado, em pó) e dizendo-se duma maneira ou doutra vai dar ao mesmo; noutros casos a ordem é relevante (desnatado, barato), e com uma ordem significa uma coisa, e significa outra com a outra ordem.

Comment: @Brent E como farias na fala?

Comment: @Jacinto Não tenho a menor idéia, mas não iria fazer diferença, devido ao meu forte sotaque de nordestino. (Inglaterra fica ao nordeste do Brasil.)

Comment: O que se passa aqui, creio, é que a linguagem não tem que obedecer à lógica do processo de fabrico; pode obedecer a uma lógica, chamemos-lhe do consumidor final, que pode primeiro classificar o produto como leite (líquido) ou leite em pó, e só depois se preocupar se o leite ou leite em pó é magro, gordo ou meio gordo. Isto leva ao leite em pó magro.

Comment: @Brent A minha resposta está um bocado caótica, e beneficiaria talvez de alguma arrumação e inclusão de alguns aspetos que penso ter clarificado nos comentários. Mas dado que já a escolheste como resposta correta, não sei se não preferirás que ela fique como está.

Comment: Acho que esta resposta está de facto demasiado e verbosa e também complica o assunto demais. Na minha opinião, a estranheza do OP é pensar que "leite em pó magro" é agrupado "leite (em pó magro)", quando na verdade é "(leite em pó) magro", o que é possível porque "leite em pó" tem coesão suficiente. "Leite barato em pó" não é bom porque o que pode ou não ser barato (=em conta) é o produto "leite em pó".

Comment: A questão mais interessante, a meu ver, é porque é que, em inglês, "skim powdered milk" é tão menos usado que "powdered skim milk" (3% das ocurrências no google)

Comment: Esta é a resposta reformulada. Podes clicar no edited e ver no original o que é uma resposta caótica. Longa não é o mesmo que verbosa. Aposto que muita gente acha verbosa a minha resposta da silepse a uma pergunta tua, e tu gostaste. Mais do que explicar a estranheza do OP, eu quis justificar as duas possibilidades. Por falar em resposta verbosa, não queres responder à minha pergunta do jajão. A resposta que lá está é insatisfatória.

Comment: @Artefacto É a lógica da forma! Possivelmente influenciada pela estratégia comercial: provavlemente quem produz leite em pó não vende leite líquido. Mas aí, _powdered_ é adjetivo, logo não se põe o problema de _skimmed_ adjetivar o pó ou o leite.

Answer (score 5):

Neste caso o correto é ***leite em pó desnatado***, e porquê? Porque *leite em pó* é o substantivo e *desnatado* o adjetivo que o caracteriza.

Podes ter o *leite em pó* (com natas) e o *leite em pó* (sem natas, ou seja, desnatado) mas o que é importante é que é **leite em pó**.

Tens vários exemplos de ***leite em pó***:

- **leite em pó** magro
- **leite em pó** meio-gordo
- **leite em pó** gordo
- **leite em pó** integral

Poderia também ser *leite desnatado em pó*, mas isso indicaria que tens uma gama de produtos de **leite desnatado**, que não faz muito sentido. E não estaria em concordância com o facto de ser leite em pó.

No fundo é uma questão de concordância com o produto que esta a ser vendido. Se estamos a vender *leite em pó* e queremos vender *leite em pó* sem natas então teremos de vender *leite em pó desnatado*.

Comment: Não sei se fui claro o suficiente.

Comment: Claríssimo, e é um argumento interessante e meritório. Mas --- não me convence.

Comment: @Jacinto porquê? O facto de ser em pó é uma caraterística do produto como "Ajax limpa vidros" e não um adjetivo que caraterize um produto.

Comment: Desculpe, mas esse é o argumento que sempre me foi apresentado. Mas para mim, "em pó" e "magro", por exemplo, parecem dois qualificadores do leite, que está ao mesmo tempo magro e em pó. Sinto que "magro" é "mais perto" de "leite" que "em pó" (canela em pó, sabão em pó, ouro em pó...), me parece mais interessante qualificar primeiro pelo adjetivpo mais afin. Também, considero que o leite foi magro *antes* de ser "em pó". Não sei se minha 'lógica' é válida, entretanto, mas me irrita por nunc ter visto pó magro.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Mas não é o pó que é magro é o produto "Leite em pó". Tenho o produto X à venda na minha loja e tenho X magro e X integral. Neste caso esse produto é o "leite em pó".

Comment: Entendo, mas não poderia ser que "tenho leite desnatado" a venda, tanto em forma líquida como em pó? Me parece que há dois eixos onde podemos cortar o bolo.

Answer (score 3):

Independente de regras gramaticais, certas expressões **consagradas pelo uso popular** tornam-se expressões fixas, i.e., seqüências de palavras memorizadas em bloco, e não há como mudá-las. Nesses casos, já não importa mais se o adjetivo deveria vir antes ou depois, ou se fere alguma regra gramatical.

São exemplos de expressões fixas: por o preto no branco, preto e branco, falsa modéstia, prós e contras, de viva voz, olhar de alto a baixo, etc.  **Não adianta discutir se deveria ser "modéstia falsa" ou "falsa modéstia".** Ou se deveríamos dizer "olhar de baixo a alto". **Quando o uso está consagrado, os prescrivistas nada podem fazer.**

Quanto ao leite em pó desnatado, **concordo com Jorge B** quando diz que "leite em pó" é o substantivo e "desnatado" o adjetivo que o qualifica. Soaria estranho, aos nossos ouvidos brasileiros, ouvir alguém dizer que comprou "leite desnatado em pó". Mas, **independente de ser uma expressão gramaticalmente certa ou errada, a voz do povo fala mais alto.**

Comment: +1 gostei do teu ponto de vista.

Comment: Concordo. Só acrescento que se alguém disser "leite desnatado em pó" todo mundo vai entender - e perceber que quem disse é gringo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Conforme alguém já disse antes, dá a impressão de que pegaram o leite desnatado e então transformaram-no em pó.

Comment: E não é assim que se fabrica o leite em pó desnatado? Duvido que retirem a nata depois de transformá-lo em pó. Como você disse, não é uma questão de lógica, e sim de consagração pelo uso. Outra coisa: eu posso estar enganado, mas acho que no Brasil o leite em pó apareceu antes do desnatado. Se isso for verdade, pode explicar a força de "leite em pó" como uma unidade, com qualquer qualificador vindo sempre no final, aplicando-se à unidade inteira, e não só a "leite".

Comment: Admito ser extremamente conservador com relação às normas gramáticas, mas acho que "consagração pelo uso popular" é uma corrida ao fundo do poço.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm very conservative with regard to the rules of grammar, but I think that letting popular usage define one's grammar is a race to the bottom.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough  "Letting" popular usage"..... Letting?   That's not the point.  When 99,99% of a people use their language in a certain way, there's nothing you can do about it.  That's what I mean by "consagração pelo uso popular".  Suppose you find "It's I"  wrong and want to reject it. Do you have a choice?

Comment: @bfavaretto     No Brasil o leite em pó já é comercializado há mais de 60 anos (não sei precisar) e o leite desnatado apareceu bem depois, talvez na década de 70.  Em termos comerciais, acho que foi assim em muitos outros países.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que vocês não estão a entender. "Leite desnatado" não é um produto como "leite em pó" ou "leite achocolatado" ou "leite". É apenas uma versão desses produtos. É como pedir um café com ou sem açúcar. Neste caso é leite com ou sem natas.