# Porque não "ele sempre tem vivido"?

Tags: ordem-de-expressões, tempo-verbal

A seguintes frases estão corretas:

> (1) Ele **tem sempre vivido** em sociedade.
>   (2) Ele **tem vivido sempre** em sociedade.
>   (3) Ele **sempre viveu** em sociedade.
>   (4) Ele **viveu sempre** em sociedade.

Diria que (1) significa ele viveu, desde que há memória, por norma e até agora, em sociedade, (2) admite a mesma leitura que (1), mas é possível lê-la também como "ultimamente, ele tem vivido ininterruptamente em sociedade", (3) não tem noção durativa e podemos admitir que não viveu em sociedade até agora mas até algum ponto no passado (especialmente recente) e (4) é mais facilmente lida como até um ponto num passado distante (por exemplo, já morreu há vários anos).

Mas esta não me soa bem:

> Ele **sempre tem vivido** em sociedade.

No entanto, admito as seguintes, embora algumas pareçam inversões da ordem normal:

> Como **sempre tem acontecido**, ...
>   Confirmando o que a família **sempre tem defendido**, ...
>    Apesar de aliada de Washington na Nato, a França **sempre tem feito** questão de diversificar os seus laços, ...

Porquê?

Comment: Eu não me vou atrever a fazer uma resposta por não ter fundamentos, mas diria que é porque nesse caso o *sempre* fica diretamente ligado com o *tem* e não com *vivido*, que será a ideia que se quer passar, como *tem **sempre vivido***.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não tenho a certeza desse facto. A minha sensibilidade é no sentido de que em "tem sempre vivido", "sempre" qualifica "tem" (pela forma como as duas palavras se podem pronunciar mais juntas), não vivido (portanto qualificará TT, ou FIN-time na terminologia de [Klein 1992](http://www.mpi.nl/world/materials/publications/Klein/089_1992_The_present_perfect_puzzle.pdf)). E não sei se em "tem vivido sempre" "sempre" qualifica "vivido" ou a expressão inteira "tem vivido".

Comment: (cont.) Ou porque pôr o "sempre" antes funciona (aparentemente) se o aspeto for iterativo, mas não na frase do título ou em "*eu sempre tenho sido bom", em que "tenho sido" tem aspeto durativo.

Comment: Faz-me lembrar esta outra pergunta: [Qual é a melhor ordem para fragmentos adjetivais?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/qual-%C3%A9-a-melhor-ordem-para-fragmentos-adjetivais-whats-the-best-order-for-a)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que não se usa o advérbio "sempre" em uma frase no Pretérito Perfeito Composto (PPC). Seria melhor, em todos os seus exemplos, utilizar o Pretérito Perfeito Simples (PPS):

"Ele sempre **viveu** em sociedade."

"Como sempre **aconteceu**, ..."
"Confirmando o que a família sempre **defendeu**, ..."
"Apesar de aliada de Washington na Nato, a França sempre **fez** questão de diversificar os seus laços..."

O PPC também não soa correto com os advérbios "nunca", "ainda não" e "já". Se você utilizar esse advérbios com o PPC, a ideia de tempo fica confusa pois dá a ideia de 2 significados temporais diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas parece-me que ela essencialmente reformula a pergunta (petitio principii). Além disso, ninguém diria que "como sempre tem acontecido, ..." está errado ou sequer soa mal. O último parágrafo diz qualquer coisa, mas precisaria de ser muito mais desenvolvido (por exemplo: quais são esses dois significados?, porque é que estar à frente faz diferença?).

Comment: Também não estou completamente convencido de que não se possam usar esses advérbios, especialmente "já". Exemplos do CETEMPúblico: "Em Freixo de Espada à Cinta ainda não temos tido problemas com o abastecimento de água, mas...", "Desde o último sábado, e por razões sempre diferentes, Jorge Sampaio nunca tem falhado.", "a malta já tem falado nisso, mas depois ninguém faz nada".

Answer (score 1):

**Ele sempre tem vivido em sociedade** também não me soa bem, mas as frases seguintes já passam:

> (a) Anda outra vez com problemas de dinheiro, que é *como ele sempre tem vivido*.
>   (b) Pois é esta vida dura *que ele sempre tem vivido.*

Do mesmo modo

> (c) Isto sempre tem acontecido.
>   (d) A família sempre tem defendido isto.

Não me soam tão bem como:

> (e) Aconteceu outra vez, como sempre tem acontecido.
>   (f) Concluiu-se que não foi suicídio, confirmando o que a família sempre tem defendido.

Ou seja, parece-me que é o **como** e **o que** que tornam o adiantamento do **sempre** mais natural.

Acho possível a diferença apontada entre (3) e (4): que **sempre viveu** possa sugerir um passado mais recente que **viveu sempre**. Mas isso é pelo contexto que cada uma me sugere. Para mim o **sempre** ganha ênfase ao ser adiantado na frase, sugerindo até alguém a rebater algo dito por outrem, o que sugere uma pessoa mais próxima dos conversantes, talvez ainda viva:

> "A certa altura ele passou a viver mais em sociedade." — "Ele sempre viveu em sociedade!"

*Ele viveu sempre em sociedade* parece-me mais neutro. Talvez seja também a questão da ênfase que torna mais natural as frases (a), (b), (e) e (f): os contextos sugerem uma enfatização do *sempre*.

Para além de *sempre* ganhar ênfase com o adiantamento, não vejo quailquer diferença entre *sempre viveu* e *viveu sempre* ou entre *tem vivido sempre, tem sempre vivido* e *sempre tem vivido*.

Answer (score 0):

Vejamos como fica com outros exemplos:

> 1. Ele tem sempre vivido em São Paulo.
> 2. Ele tem vivido sempre em São Paulo.
> 3. Ele sempre viveu em São Paulo.
> 4. Ele viveu sempre em São Paulo.

1 e 2 soam muito unusual. Não vejo uma situação onde eu usaria esses tempos verbais no contexto de "viver".
Não percebo nenhuma diferença de significado entre 3 e 4.

Usos:

> (a) "Você vive no Rio de Janeiro?"
>
> (b) "Não, eu vivo em São Paulo."
>
> (a) "Mas viveu no Rio de Janeiro durante algum tempo."
>
> (b) "Não, eu sempre vivi em São Paulo."  ou "Eu vivi sempre em São Paulo.

ou

> (a) "Ele mora em Lisboa, certo?"
>
> (b) "Não, ele mora no Faro."
>
> (a) "Mas morou em Lisboa quando era jovem?"
>
> (b) "Não, ele sempre morou no Faro" ou "Ele morou sempre no Faro"

ou

> (a) "Ele foi pontual?"
>
> (b) "Não, ele chegou atrasado."
>
> (a) "Mas ele costumava ser pontual, não?
>
> (b) "Ele sempre chegou atrasado." ou "Ele chegou sempre atrasado."

Não vejo diferença alguma entre as duas formas acima.
Contudo, não consigo imaginar um brasileiro falando:

> - "Ele tem sempre vivido em São Paulo". ou "Ele tem vivido sempre em São Paulo."
> - "Ele tem sempre morado no Faro." ou "Ele tem morado sempre no Faro."

Mas consigo imaginar:

> - "Ele sempre tem chegado atrasado"
> - "Ele tem chegado sempre atrasado"

ou

> - "Eu tenho sempre sido bom p'ra ela."
> - "Eu tenho sido sempre bom p'ra ela."

O primeiro dos dois últimos exemplos dá a sensação de que ele não costumava chegar sempre atrasado. Atrasava uma vez ou outra, ou então não atrasava nunca.  Mas passou a atrasar de algum tempo inespecificado até a presente data.

Da mesma forma o segundo exemplo transmite um significado de "ação habitual", que é repetida várias vezes até o presente momento. Esta forma verbal não pode ser usada para ações que só acontecem uma vez: viver, morrer, ser batizado, doar um rim, ser enterrado, etc.

Comment: Posso dizer que em Portugal, "ele sempre chegou atrasado" é diferente de "ele chegou sempre atrasado". A primeira diz que era habitual (desde sempre) que ele chegasse atrasado, enquanto a segunda diz que "não houve uma única vez que ele deixado de chegar atrasado". A primeira deixa aberta a possibilidade de que ele tenha chegado a horas algumas vezes (mas não era esse o hábito). Concordo contigo no significado de "ele tem chegado sempre atrasado"/"ele sempre tem chegado atrasado".

Comment: De qualquer forma, escapaste à pergunta. Se não gostas do meu exemplo, podes usar "eu sempre tenho sido bom" vs "eu tenho sempre sido bom"/"eu tenho sido sempre bom". A questão é porque é que as útimas formas são admissíveis e a primeira não.

Comment: @Artefacto   Editado.

Comment: Embora seja verdade que o PPC tenha geralmente um significado habitual/iterativo, este não tem de ser o caso. Podes ver [este artigo](http://www.letras.ufpr.br/documentos/pdf_revistas/ilari55.pdf), de resto brasileiro. Como esse artigo diz, pode ter um "aspeto durativo", que é o caso de "ele tem vivido bem", "tenho estado doente". E em todo o caso, por que é que a posição de "sempre" é relevante não ficou claro.